# What funded research projects are going on in the field of vegetarianism?

Tags: veganism, research

Is vegetarianism a well researched topic? By asking this question I mean university and industry level research. Livestock has more financially strong background so industry people and government invest in research related to this. But considering the low ratio vegetarianism, I would like to get some insight regarding research funding in vegetarianism research. So, if somebody can sight some example of university or government or industry funded research project in the field of vegetarianism.

Comment: Good question for a debate, but I think it's difficult to answer in the StackExchange style..

Comment: I understand your point and I tried to edit my question to make it more relevant for stackExchange format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't provide a list of all university level vegetarian research. However, one of the leaders in research into vegetarian diet is worked done by the [Loma Linda school of Public Health](http://publichealth.llu.edu/adventist-health-studies/findings). Loma Linda, was one of the blue zones for longevity in the famous article by [National Geographic](http://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2015/04/11/398325030/eating-to-break-100-longevity-diet-tips-from-the-blue-zones) a few years ago.

The research at Loma Linda includes comparisons of various vegetarian/vegan diets as well.